# Neo4j seemingly does not import plugin

Tags: neo4j

I have written a custom function, which I would like to import into Neo4j. Nor Neo4j or java complain about anything. I placed the jar under the $NEO4j_HOME/plugins directory and restarted the db, yet the function is no where to be seen.

Here are the logs:

```
2022-09-13 08:52:42.606+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2022-09-13 08:52:42.606+0000 INFO  Stopped.
2022-09-13 08:53:53.414+0000 INFO  Starting...
2022-09-13 08:53:54.015+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{<private>} (<private>)
2022-09-13 08:53:56.003+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.4.5 ========
2022-09-13 08:53:59.138+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at /Users/<private>/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-541daf17-c602-49ef-9aab-bab9aeb69c4f/metrics
2022-09-13 08:53:59.194+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2022-09-13 08:54:00.508+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2022-09-13 08:54:00.516+0000 INFO  id: <private>
2022-09-13 08:54:00.516+0000 INFO  name: system
2022-09-13 08:54:00.516+0000 INFO  creationDate: 2022-09-13T08:30:37.347Z
2022-09-13 08:54:00.516+0000 INFO  Started.
2022-09-13 08:54:45.595+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2022-09-13 08:54:45.597+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2022-09-13 08:54:50.699+0000 INFO  Stopped.
2022-09-13 08:54:56.619+0000 INFO  Starting...
2022-09-13 08:54:57.174+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{<private>} (<private>)
2022-09-13 08:54:59.097+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.4.5 ========
2022-09-13 08:55:02.071+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at /Users/<private>/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-541daf17-c602-49ef-9aab-bab9aeb69c4f/metrics
2022-09-13 08:55:02.124+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2022-09-13 08:55:03.337+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2022-09-13 08:55:03.346+0000 INFO  id: <private>
2022-09-13 08:55:03.346+0000 INFO  name: system
2022-09-13 08:55:03.346+0000 INFO  creationDate: 2022-09-13T08:30:37.347Z
2022-09-13 08:55:03.346+0000 INFO  Started.
```

When I run: `SHOW FUNCTIONS YIELD *` I do not see mine listed.

```
@UserFunction
@Description("procedure.getPixelDist(012345678, 012345678, 10) - calculate the distance between the two pixels.")
public boolean getPixelDist(@Name("p1") String pixelOne, @Name("p2") String pixelSecond,
                               @Name("threshold") Integer threshold) throws Exception;
```

I have tried everything, that I could find on the internet to fix it.
Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you are copying to the right neo4j instance ? afaik, `Integer` is not allowed as a datatype in the parameters. You would see some errors in the logs

Comment: Yes. I tried to use an String Array instead for pixelSecond, and it complained. After I changed it to a string, Neo4j stopped complaining). Probably Integer is not an know datatype, but Java can cast from int to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from putting your jar file in /plugins folder, you also need to update your configuration file /conf/neo4j.conf to allow customized functions/procedures.

```
dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=* 
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=*
```

Add it in $NEO4j_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf, then restart your neo4j server.

References:
https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.4/security/securing-extensions/

Comment: isn't it that, if you don't have this configuration all procedures would be loaded ?

Comment: unfortunately, this did not fix it. Do you know my coincidence, in what file I could find the logs, for the loading of plugins?

Comment: You configure security.procedures. I use a custom function, are the flags in neo4j the same?

Comment: please give me your jar file and I will test it on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your help :), here is the link to the jar: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C1d5nrZSFDB_7xvQyBr3gDEiIg3sMcoo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your jar is faulty - it doesn't have the class file in it. Make sure it is built correctly. If you use maven, here is a handy template - https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/project-setup/

Comment: Sorry, I renamed a folder last minute (and did not test it). Here is the current version of the plugin inside the db: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NnnZ0097X_jO-gCGcvTN-HRqvpt-01vm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its the same - there is no class file in the jar. You can extract it and check the files in the jar

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! My mistake was, I didn't call maven compile before I ran the jar'ing part. I do not understand why maven wouldn't compile the source code when running the jar command. Anyways, thank you for saving me probably another 5h of searching for the problem :)